# Is www included in the server name in apache virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm looking to set up VirtualHosts on my apache server and was looking for documentation that would tell me if these 2 entries are identical

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName example1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice the lack of `www.` in the second one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the Apache docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername):

> The ServerName directive sets the hostname and port that the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating redirection URLs. For example, if the name of the machine hosting the web server is simple.example.com, but the machine also has the DNS alias www.example.com and you wish the web server to be so identified, the following directive should be used:
>
> ServerName www.example.com:80

So I guess they are not identical.